# Does every infinite set have a denumerable subset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question is answered with a mere "Yes" in the textbook (Theory of Sets by Joseph Breuer), but I'm not sure where the confidence comes from. For instance, if we have a non-denumerable set, then it seems to me that no matter what pattern we choose, we'll end up with a subset with the same cardinal number. Or won't we?

I guess what makes matters worse is that the question right after proving the theorem that "If a denumrable set is subtracted from a non-denumrable set, the resulting set is no-denumerable." I understood the proof, and can even reproduce it perfectly, but I have no idea I understand what it means. An example would make things clearer, I guess.

I'm thoroughly confused; please help!

Comment: But think of , e.g. $\mathbb Z$ as a subset of the non-denumerable Real numbers. An example of your situation would be removing the rationals from the reals, and then the irrationals remain.

Comment: For example, the reals are non-denumerable, but they certainly have a countably infinite subset, the natural numbers, and many others. For a proof, it depends how formal you want to be, and whether you want to take the Axiom of Choice for granted. But informally, take an element $a_0$ from the set, then another, which we call $a_1$, and so on. We end up with a countably infinite subset.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $S$ be a non-denumerable set (*uncountable* is a more common term in English texts IMVHO). The set $S$ is not empty, so you can pick an element $s_1\in S$. The set $S\setminus\{s_1\}$ is non-empty (for otherwise the set $S$ had turned out to  be finite and thus also countable), so you can pick $s_2\in S\setminus\{s_1\}$.
You can continue this by recursively selecting an element $s_{k+1}\in S\setminus\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_k\}$ for all natural numbers $k$.

By construction the chosen elements $s_i,i\in\mathbf{N},$ are all distinct, so they form a countably infinite subset of $S$.

Comment: I would just like to point out that in order to justify the continuation of this process to get an actual infinite set, something like the axiom of dependent choice is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the extras, guys. I'm blissfully ignorant about those finer points as: "I believe in naïve set theory and Zorn's lemma (and steer clear from Russell's paradox)". Largely for practical reasons :-/ The other ignorami are referred to [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) [two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice) Wikipedia-articles for some quick reading.

Comment: Thank you, @JyrkiLahtonen! That was very helpful, although the Axiom of Choice hasn't been introduced in the book yet.

Answer (score 1):

For an example, consider the set $\Bbb R$: it’s uncountable, and it has $\Bbb Q$, the rationals, and $\Bbb Z$, the integers, as countable subsets. If you remove either of these from $\Bbb R$, what’s left is still uncountable.

The claim that every infinite set has a countably infinite subset actually depends on the axiom of choice: without the axiom of choice it need not be true. I’ll sketch one of several possible proofs using the axiom of choice. First one proves that the axiom of choice implies that every set can be well-ordered. Now let $X$ be any infinite set. If $X$ is countably infinite, there’s nothing to prove, so suppose that $X$ is uncountable, and let $\preceq$ be a well-ordering of $X$.

For each $x\in X$ let $\operatorname{pred}(x)=\{y\in X:y\prec x\}$, the set of predecessors of $x$. Let $I=\{x\in X:\operatorname{pred}(x)\text{ is infinite}\}$; then $I\ne\varnothing$, so let $x_0=\min I$; then $\operatorname{pred}(x_0)$ is a countably infinite subset of $X$.

Comment: And if min$I$ doesn't exist/is $-\infty$?

Comment: @JLA: $\min I$ always exists: $\preceq$ is a [well-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order), meaning that every non-empty subset of $X$ has a least element with respect to $\preceq$.

Comment: Does the fact that pred$(x_0)$ is countable rely on the axiom of choice? ie. something like take a sequence $y_n$ converging to $x_0$, then  pred$(x_0)=\cup_{\{y_n:y_n<x_0}\} \text{pred}(y_n)$ is a countable union of finite sets.

Comment: @JLA: No, the only use of choice in this argument was to say that there is a well-order on $X$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem) for a little more information.

Comment: So how do you know pred$(x_0)$ is countable?

Comment: @JLA: That takes a little work to prove; remember, I only *sketched* the argument. One way is to show that for each $n\in\Bbb N$ there is exactly one $y_n\prec x_0$ such that $|\operatorname{pred}(y)|=n$. Since by the choice of $x_0$ we know that $\operatorname{pred}(y)$ is finite for each $y\prec x_0$, this establishes a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\operatorname{pred}(x_0)$.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just thought I was missing something immediately obvious.

Comment: @JLA: Only if you already know this stuff thoroughly! :-)