# If every denumerable subset of a relation is bijective, then is the relation bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are uncountable sets.

Also suppose that $R \subseteq X \times Y$ and $ 
 \begin{vmatrix}    R \end{vmatrix}   \neq \begin{vmatrix}   \mathbb {N} \end{vmatrix} $

If there exists a countable subset of $R$ and for every countable subset of $R$ there exists $ X^{\prime }
\subseteq X$ and exists $ Y^{\prime } 
\subseteq Y$ such that $R$  is a one-to-one correspondence from $ X^{\prime }$ to $ Y^{\prime }$ then does that necessarily imply that $R$ is a one-to-one correspondence from $X$ to $Y$?

---

#### Clarifications:

- $R$ is a  [$\text{relation}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics))  from set $X$ to set $Y$.
- When I wrote that "$R$ was a one-to-one correspondence from $X^{\prime }$ to $Y^{\prime }$" I probably should have said that the following subset of $R$ represents a one-to-one correspondence from $X^{\prime}$ to $Y^{\prime }$: $\begin{Bmatrix}(x, y): (x, y) \in R \text{ and } x \in X^{\prime} \text{ and }  y \in Y^{\prime} \end{Bmatrix}$

Comment: 1. You probably meant _"... such that $R\cap(X'\times Y')$ is a one-to-one correspondence from $X'$ to $Y'$..."_, right? 2. Will something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/474832/) work in a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Can you give more context? As written your question does not meet site standards.(It already has one close vote)

Comment: To me, the question is clear as it is and does not need any additional context. A demonstration of effort and challenge would be good though. (Also remove the typo in the title)

Comment: @user14111 The conclusion is supposed to be that $R$ is a one-to-one correspondence between $X$ and $Y$, not that there exists any-old pair of sets such that  $R$ is a one-to-one correspondence between that pair of sets.

Comment: @user14111 Yes, my assumptions are satisfied if $X=[0,1]$, $Y=[0,2]$ and $R=\{(x,x):x∈X\}$. I wish that I had added that $X = \{x \in X: \exists y \in Y: (x,y) ∈R\}$. It is too late now though.